# What are the pros and cons of bundling webdriver-io with the main application at test?

Tags: webdriver-io

What are the cons and pros of bundling webdriver-io with the main application at test?
The question is based on the assumption that webdriver-io could be run as a stand-alone application, but also bundled together with the main application (similar to Cypress).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebdriverIO comes in two flavors , one is runner and another is standalone.

Runner is a framework which has all boiler plate codes for reporting , integration etc already done for you.

standalone mode is just like selenium , its just a http client library that calls w3c protocol under the hood .

so what flavor you use depends on your use case. For end to end test we usually prefer runner . while if you already have a framework in place then you can use wdio standalone as a replacement of webdriverjs